# Для чего нужен вот этот метода hasErrors()?

Tags: yii, yii2

Для чего тут используется метод hasErrors()? Нам не ясно, может поможет кто, подскажет как правильно интерпретировать его описание?

> Returns a value indicating whether there is any validation error.
>
> Возвращает значение индикатора/указателя, когда находит любую ошибку.

Мы не знаем как это понять.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#hasErrors()-detail

```
public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Возвращает значение, указывающее, существует ли какая-либо ошибка валидации.........то есть `true/false`....... есть ошибки - возвращает `true`, не было ошибок при проверке - возвращает `false` .......а не  возвращает указатели/индикаторы....где вы такой перевод нашли-то....

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Большое Вам спасибо за ответ. А разве этот  метод `validate()`  не делает тоже самое? Я так понимаю что можно было бы просто `validate()` вызвать вместо `hasErrors()`. Если Вас не затруднит, не могли бы Вы дать свой ответ, в виде ответа, для будущих пользователей?

Comment: `validate` конечно является оберткой над `hasErrors` и в итог его работы `return !$this->hasErrors()`, но при этом сам он более глубокий, т.к. внутри происходит еще множество других различных проверок (даже можно посмотреть в `Model.php -> validate()`), а также применяются `beforeValidate` и `afterValidate` где еще куча каких-либо проверок может быть...  и по факту применяется к конкретному сценарию....... `hasErrors` не привязан к сценариям, просто тупенький маленький простенький метод

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Это 100% точная  информация? Спасибо. Приятного Вам дня.

Answer (score 1):

Верное описание уже дали в комментах, приведу небольшой практический пример.

Допустим, у вас есть авторизация пользователя по логину и паролю, и, пользователь может так же оказаться в бане.

Логично высветить надпись "этот пользователь забанен" **только после** успешного ввода логина и пароля. Вот собственно так и делаете: метод `checkBan()` вызываете после проверки логина и пароля и внутри кода `if (!$this->hasErrors()) {`